# Looping with booleans in Python

Tags: python-2.7, loops, boolean, python-webbrowser

Trying to automate a process in checking websites to see if they exist.

Basically, I've imported a list of websites from Excel into my program, and I'm trying to see if the exact web address exists. I am trying to create a control structure that, for all of the cells in this list, I can check if the cell (web address) exists or not, and then store that output to another list. Coming from a Java background, I am thinking I want to loop in this type of manner:

```
newlist = []
for data

    if webbrowser.open(data[row][1]) == true

        store true at this point in newlist

    else

        store false at this point in newlist
```

I am new to Python and don't quite understand the nuances used in the looping mechanisms and how booleans are used differently than in Java.

If you could offer any suggestions, I would be very appreciative. Sorry if I've mislabled/mistagged this.

Comment: I am working with a large list of websites (~5000) so I am trying to make sure that when the code executes, it just checks to see if the website exists without actually opening the website. Not sure if the webbrowser module allows this, however.

Answer (score 1):

A pythonix way could be:

```
result = [webbrowser.open(row[1]) == True for row in data]
```

Comment: @ivo Thanks for the clarification

Comment: `true` is not a valid symbol.  Try `newlist = [bool(webbrowser.open(row[1])) for row in data]`.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson Thanks!